# Why does lazy val behave so mysteriously in enumeration, Scala?

Tags: scala, enums, lazy-evaluation

I want to find lazily the maximum of all defined enum value names. The following piece of code when executed falls into an endless loop printing repeatedly `InvocationTargetException`.

```
object Enum extends Enumeration with App {
  val A, B = new Val
  lazy val foo = values.maxBy(_.toString)

  println(Enum.foo)
}
```

The problem does not appear when `foo` is a `def`.

Why does it behave like this? Shouldn't `lazy val` be just a memorized `def`?

Oddly, the following piece of code does work as expected:

```
object Enum extends Enumeration with App {
  val A, B = new Val
  lazy val foo = values.foldLeft(""){(a, b) => a + b}

  println(Enum.foo)
}
```

I'm using scala 2.11.7.

// --- Solution

The problem is that foo is of `Value` type and thus is interpreted as an enum value. 
A way around the problem is creating a proxy `def` to `lazy val` as in the following piece of code:

```
object Enum extends Enumeration with App {
  val A, B = new Val
  private lazy val fooBuffer = values.maxBy(_.toString)
  def foo = fooBuffer

  println(Enum.foo)
}
```

Comment: Works ok with scala 2.11. What scala do you have?

Comment: @Archeg I'm using 2.11.7

Comment: I'm not sure why it behaves so weird - when I increased the name of `B` to `BBBBBBB` it starts to throw an exception as well. But you set `foo` into one of the `Val` that are already defined which I don't think `Enum` supports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two issues are that `App` must be initialized by `Enum main null`.

Then, `Enumeration` looks for vals of type `Val`, which includes your member `foo`, which is probably not intended.

Sample mayhem:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Enum extends Enumeration with App {
  val A, B = new Val
  lazy val foo = values.maxBy(_.toString)

  println(Enum.foo)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Enum

scala> Enum main null
foo

scala> Enum.foo
res2: Enum.Value = foo

scala> Enum.values
res3: Enum.ValueSet = Enum.ValueSet(A, foo)
```

Just to show that fixing the type fixes the SO:

```
scala> object X extends Enumeration { val x, y, z = new Val ; lazy val f: Any = values.maxBy(_.toString) }
defined object X

scala> X.f
res2: Any = z
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you initialise your object, but I see a `StackOverflowError` instead (no matter whether you have delayed init through `App` or not):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:264)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:161)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:161)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:259)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:258)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:270)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.filter(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.Enumeration.scala$Enumeration$$populateNameMap(Enumeration.scala:161)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$scala$Enumeration$$nameOf$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:180)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$scala$Enumeration$$nameOf$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:180)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.Enumeration.scala$Enumeration$$nameOf(Enumeration.scala:180)
  at scala.Enumeration$Val.toString(Enumeration.scala:223)
  at Enum$$anonfun$foo$1.apply(<console>:55)
  at Enum$$anonfun$foo$1.apply(<console>:55)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$maxBy$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$maxBy$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:240)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.maxBy(TraversableOnce.scala:240)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.maxBy(Traversable.scala:104)
  at Enum$.foo$lzycompute(<console>:55)
  at Enum$.foo(<console>:55)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$scala$Enumeration$$populateNameMap$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:168)
  at scala.Enumeration$$anonfun$scala$Enumeration$$populateNameMap$1.apply(Enumeration.scala:165)
...
```

The reason is horrible [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L156) that is doing some dirty reflection heuristics. Basically `populateNameMap` looks for values of type `Value` in the body of the enumeration. Since `lazy val foo` *does* have type `Value` that is included in the body of `populateNameMap`. So you have an infinite loop here.

When you change from `lazy val` to `def` the `populateNameMap` doesn't include `foo` any longer because it is not a `ValDef`.